# How to replace authors names with unique numbers in java using hashmap

Tags: java, replace, hashmap

I have a CSV file which is a coauthorship network.Entries are like this:

```
1992,M_DINE,R_LEIGH,P_HUET,A_LINDE,D_LINDE

1992,C_BURGESS,J_CLINE,M_LUTY

1992,M_DINE,R_LEIGH,P_HUET,A_LINDE,D_LINDE

1992,F_ZWIRNER

1992,O_HERNANDEZ
...
```

I want to replace all the authors names with unique numbers using hashmaps
I want the output to be sth like this:

```
    M_DINE   1

    R_LEIGH  2

    P_HUET   3

    ...
```

and I do not want the years to be included.

Comment: Unique to what? What are the numbers for?

Comment: seems like you have the answer - use a hashmap to map authors to unqiue ids, are you asking how to use a hashmap ??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is actually a "gimme-teh-codez" request.

Comment: By unique I mean not repeatitive.
This question is not off-topic.why are you guys mad at me?I donot think my qestion have problems!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a collection of author names, Read each line, split on comma, discard year, for each author if collection does not contain author name then add it to the collection. Then read from the collection and assign number.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you've explained everything you want to do.

You'll need a few objects.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> authorList = new HashMap<>();
int authorCounter = 0;
```

The map, obviously, and a counter to track your index.

I don't know what your main method is, but you need to process the input.

```
public void foo() {
    // ... handle the file import through scanner in
    while(in.hasNext()) {
        String input = in.next();
        String[] authors = input.split(',');
        for(int i = 1; i < authors.length; i++) { //skip index 0 because that's the year
            addAuthor(authors[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a really plain `addAuthor` function. You probably want to extract it into `hasAuthor` and `getAuthorId` and so on, but this will just add an author if it doesn't find it with the latest iterated counter.

```
void addAuthor(String s) {
    if(authorList.get(s) == null)
        authorList.put(s, ++authorCounter);
}
```

Comment: I wrote my code and I want to write the results in another csv file. but it's not working.It doesn't have errors but the output is wrong :(